# OpenCascade link error in c++ using vs2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, opencascade

I am a newbie to Open Cascade.After building occt-7.3.0-vc14-64 with cmake with no error, i added inc/ in Include Directories and added win64/vc14/libd/ in Library Directories, then added only "include" in main.cpp. But after clicked debug button, i got link error as following:

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl 
Standard_OutOfMemory::Standard_OutOfMemory(char const * const)" (?? 
0Standard_OutOfMemory@@QEAA@QEBD@Z) referenced in function "public: 
void __cdecl Standard_OutOfMemory::`default constructor closure'(void)" 
(??_FStandard_OutOfMemory@@QEAAXXZ)
```

What else should have be done?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is that can't find lib that contain `Standard_OutOfMemory`.

`Standard_OutOfMemory` is a class in `TKernel.dll`, you should add `TKernel.lib` to project's ***`Additional Dependencies`***, like on the image below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works.BTW, how to find out that Standard_OutOfMemory is a class in TKernel.dll?

Comment: Just search this class by name under source code folder, or it is very easy to search via visual studio